# AWS EC2 Instance lost its internet after reboot - Ubuntu OS

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, amazon

I am really not good with servers. So what happened is that I rebooted my EC2 Instance with Ubuntu as the Operating System. I rebooted it via the EC2 Instance console.

Now when it turned back on, it seems it can't connect to the internet. I noticed this one because I have a web server in my instance then it says "Please check your internet connection and try again", then I also try to download some packages, it also says "failed to fetch..."

Is there a way to turn back the internet on?

I really badly needed help on this because my live server isn't working! :(

Thanks and your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your server is not connected to internet , then you can't connect to it. As you mentioned you tried to download some package means your sever is connected to the internet. So better raise the ticket to aws team. They will look into it. Or else stop the server and start again

Comment: Thank you, it worked when i rebooted the server.

Comment: I suspect that you actually may have a problem with your netplan .yaml configuration. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.